# Why is Three.js video not rendering on my Nexus 7

Tags: android, google-chrome, three.js, html5-video

Trying to run the Three.js examples on the Nexus 7 and most of them work fine.
But im particularly interested in getting webgl video rendering to work on my nexus 7 device and this doesn't seem to work. All im getting is a black screen where the video is supposed to render, the rest surrounding the video renders just as normal.

My Nexus 7 is running android 4.4.4 & Chrome 36.0.1985.135 and im not seeing any console errors when running these examples.

The examples that don't work are:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/canvas_materials_video.html
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_materials_video.html

My assumption (and from what i read) is that this could have something to do with the texture size, its needs to be the power of 2. Do you guys have any clue on why its not working and what i could try to get it working?

Many thanks for your help already

Best,

Erik

Comment: It's because, as yet, there's no way for JavaScript to grab the image from the video on any mobile platform

Comment: @imcg I'm not sure that's correct. I think the problem is that videos don't auto-play on mobile devices.

Comment: Oh sorry for the misinformation, I assumed video texture was using canvas drawImage which the last time I checked didn't work for video on mobile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just guessing but AFAIK videos don't autoplay on mobile devices. To fix the issue you need to make the user click something and in the handler for that click start the video playing. The easiest way might be to make a fullscreen div with no content that has its css z-index set to something so it's above everything else. Once the user clicks it start the video and remove it.